# Canadian Lawyer Ethics

Tags: canada, ontario, professional-ethics

In Canada/Ontario, lawyers are bound by the Law Society of Upper Canada. Is there some specific statute/law/code that one can cite that prevents lawyers from harassing clients of the other party in the case which may include releasing confidential information of those clients in public?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [Rules](https://lso.ca/about-lso/legislation-rules/rules-of-professional-conduct/complete-rules-of-professional-conduct)

By and large, the lawyer has a duty to *their* client and the administration of justice - they have more limited duties to others including their client's opponent.

[Chapter 3](https://lso.ca/about-lso/legislation-rules/rules-of-professional-conduct/chapter-3) deals with confidentiality but it is almost exclusively couched in terms of the duty they owe their client. If the information you refer to is confidential business affairs of *their* client (which it may or may not be) then there are restrictions on when and to whom it can be disclosed.

If it isn't then [Chapter 2](https://lso.ca/about-lso/legislation-rules/rules-of-professional-conduct/chapter-2) which requires "a duty to carry on the practice of law and discharge all responsibilities to clients, tribunals, the public and other members of the profession honourably and with integrity" may prevent disclosure.